# How to run only 64 bit abi test cases in android CTS excluding 32 bit for (Lolliop)?

Tags: android, cts

Ive been trying to run only 64 bit abi for android CTS, the option provided in the document is run cts --abi 64 , but that is giving configuration error.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've downloaded suitable package for Lollipop from https://source.android.com/compatibility/downloads.html

In Android CTS 5.1_r1, you can use `--force-abi` option, for example:

```
run cts --force-abi 64 --package android.core.tests.libcore.package.harmony_java_io
```